# What happens first? Dissolution or solvation?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Can somebody help with the phenomenon what happens first?
Dissolution or Solvation.
I am bit confused with it

Comment: They happen together.

Answer (score 2):

"Solvation, also sometimes called dissolution, is the process of attraction and association of molecules of a solvent with molecules or ions of a solute. As ions dissolve in a solvent they spread out and become surrounded by solvent molecules."

Source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvation